# How to make a Raspberry Pi into a tablet?

Tags: touchscreen

I am interested in making a tablet out of the Raspberry Pi, a touch screen, and some sort of case. Could someone

1. Please tell me if [this touch screen](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Lilliput-12-1-16-9-SKD-Open-Frame-Touch-Screen-VGA-HDMI-DVI-Monitor-/290846125206?pt=US_Car_Monitors_w_o_Player&hash=item43b7c7ac96) would work *&*
2. where to find a case for the whole thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It won't work, in the sense that it wont be portable as a tablet. The screen you mentioned in the link requires:

> Input Voltage: DC 11-13 V

If, however, you're happy to have it plugged in, I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work, although I'm not sure how you would get the touch screen to interact with the pi.

[Here](http://www.chalk-elec.com/?page_id=1280#!/~/category/id=3094861&inview=product14647624&offset=0&sort=priceAsc) is another solution

It is rated at 5 Volts, like the Pi. If you can get a battery that delivers 5 V, there is no reason why you can't have this portable.

Charging is another issue though, you would need to find a way to charge the battery, but wouldn't be too much of a problem if you look around.

There is a youtube link that shows the touch screen interface working and is powered by USB (like the pi). These could easily be incorporated into a case.

If you find a case on an electronics website (possibly RS, for example) you can modify it to fit the Pi, the HDMI extension board, and a battery. Then you've made yourself a portable Pi-Tablet.

Hmm.... Piblet?

I saw a link somewhere at work, someone created something VERY similar, powered by battery, however it wasn't in a case. I will try and find the link and show you. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: +1 for doing your research better then I did! Forgot totally to check the voltages, good call!

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for boxes or handheld enclosures on Digikey.com

I bought something like this for my pi-tablet which I'm still working on:

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/1599TABLBK/HM1263-ND/3727459

Comment: You could also just make a case on http://123dapp.com and have it 3d printed.  Then it is the right size for whatever you want in there.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit late for you, but for other people who are looking for a Raspberry Pi based tablet, check out the PiTablet at:

http://www.PiTablet.com

It is a 10 inch capacitive touchscreen monitor, USB power pack, and lasercut acrylic case. The case files are open-source, so you can customize it however you want.

Comment: Commercial posts are not forbidden, but you should make clear that you are behind this kickstarter project. Also while this is a funded project its delivery date is still months away - this should be mentioned here as well.

Comment: I want to find a touchscreen to make a model. How did you source yours? Is there a good place to look for them?

Answer (score 0):

I can only take a shot at your first question, that screen will work. It has the correct input options to work with the HDMI output on the RPi. The touchscreen interface normally functions just like a mouse, so that should also not be a problem.